# SQL Server upgrade error (status is "Complete with failures")

Tags: sql-server, upgrade

When upgrading SQL Server from 2017 to 2019, I get this error:

[image: 1]

Comment: you have to read the summary log file that has been mentioned in the picture to find out more about the error

Comment: Are you running the setup from a mounted ISO?

Comment: You should post the contents of the summary file here if more assistance is needed. If you solved your problem, you can also answer your own question to help others later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running the setup from a mounted ISO, copy the content of media to a local drive and start setup.exe from this location.

Also please check if you have any SSMS that is version 18.x which is older than version 18.3.1. If you have then uninstall this first. If you need SSMS then proceed install the latest version from [Download SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15). After this try running the setup that you have copied locally and check if the installation can now proceed.